# typeDef not passing between classes (likey)

Tags: c++, syntax, typedef

Right so I'm building a neural network in C++ as a starting project, I've however run into a (likely) simple problem with type definition between classes. I'm working in visual studio 2015 if that matters.

So when I build the project I get the following error(s)

-> syntax error: identifier 'layer' (line 26 - Neuron.h)

-> syntax error: identifier 'layer' (line 26 - Neuron.h) [yes it lists it twice]

-> 'Neuron::feedForward' function does not take 1 arguments (line 37 Net.cpp)

-> unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include stdafx.h to your source?  (line 37 neuron.cpp) [not important most likely...]

When I highlight the value of the type in visual studio in the Neuron.h I get the following definition:

typedef std::vector <<'error-type'>> Layer.

Now it's pretty clear that as you'll see below in the code, that the Neuron class isn't properly using the typedef from the net class (included both into each other as includes). However I have no idea how to actually fix this problem.

Here's the code:

net.h

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Neuron.h"
//#include "TypeDefNeuralNet.h"


typedef std::vector<Neuron> Layer;
class Net {


public: 



    Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology);
    void feedForward(const std::vector<double> &inputVals);
    void backProp(const std::vector<double> &targetVales);
    void getResults(std::vector<double> &inputVals) const;
private:
    std::vector<Layer> m_layers; //m_layers[layerNum][neuronNum]
    double m_error;
    double m_recentAverageError;
    double m_recentAverageSoothingFacror;


};
```

Net.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Net.h"


/*
class constructors and methods for Net.cpp/.h
*/
Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology) {
    unsigned numLayers = topology.size();

    for (unsigned layerNum = 0; layerNum < numLayers; layerNum++) {
        m_layers.push_back(Layer());
        unsigned numOutputs = layerNum == topology.size() - 1 ? 0 : topology[layerNum + 1]; //inline or num outputs == 0 if last index or (:) topology at next index


        for (unsigned neuronNum = 0; neuronNum <= topology[layerNum]; neuronNum++) { //add bias neuron with <=
            m_layers.back().push_back(Neuron(numOutputs, neuronNum));

            std::cout << "made a neuron" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}

void Net::feedForward(const std::vector<double> &inputVals) {
    assert(inputVals.size() == m_layers[0].size());
    //set input
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < inputVals.size(); k++) {
        m_layers[0][k].setOutputVal(inputVals[k]); 
    }

    //feedforward
    for (unsigned layerNum = 1; layerNum < m_layers.size(); layerNum++)
    {
        Layer &prevLayer = m_layers[layerNum - 1]; //get previous layer
        for (unsigned neuron = 0; neuron < m_layers[layerNum].size()-1; neuron++) {
            m_layers[layerNum][neuron].feedForward(prevLayer);
        }
    }
}


void Net::backProp(const std::vector<double> &inputVals) {

}

void Net::getResults(std::vector<double> &inputVals) const {

}
```

Neuron.h

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include "Net.h"


struct Connections {
    double weight;
    double deltaWeight;
};


class Neuron {
public:
    //constructor
    Neuron(unsigned numOutputs, unsigned myIndex);

    //getters setters
    void setOutputVal(double val) { m_outputVal = val;  };
    double getOutputVal() { return m_outputVal; };

    //function
    void feedForward(Layer &prevousLayer); 

private:
    double m_outputVal;
    unsigned m_myIndex;
    std::vector<Connections> m_outputWeights;
    static double randomWeight();
    static double transferFunction(double x);
    static double transferFunctionDervivative(double x);

};
```

Neuron.cpp

```
#include "Neuron.h"

Neuron::Neuron(unsigned numOutputs, unsigned myIndex) {

    for (unsigned k; k < numOutputs; k++)
    {
        m_outputWeights.push_back(Connections()); 
        m_outputWeights[k].weight = randomWeight(); 
    }
    m_myIndex = myIndex;
}

double Neuron::randomWeight() {
    return rand() / double(RAND_MAX);
}


void Neuron::feedForward(Layer &prevLayer) {

    double sum = 0.0; 
    for (unsigned pn = 0; pn < prevLayer.size(); pn++) {
        sum += prevLayer[pn].getOutputVal() *
            prevLayer[pn].m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].weight;
    }
    m_outputVal = Neuron::transferFunction(sum);
} 



double Neuron::transferFunction(double x) {
    return tanh(x); 
}

double Neuron::transferFunctionDervivative(double x){
    return 1 - x*x;
}
```

NeuroNetTestProject.cpp (entry point) likely no issues here, but included.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Net.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //e.g. 


    vector<unsigned> topology;
    topology.push_back(3);
    topology.push_back(2);
    topology.push_back(1);

    Net myNet(topology);

    std::vector<double> inputVals; 
    std::vector<double> targetVals;
    std::vector<double> resultVals;


    myNet.feedForward(inputVals);
    myNet.backProp(targetVals);
    myNet.getResults(resultVals);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

anyways the error my bet would be on the identifier of layer not passing around, how do I fix this? And avoid this in the future?

Comment: You can't have circular includes in C++. Your `net.h` includes `neuron.h` and vice-versa.

Comment: You have a circular dependency, where `net.h` depends on `neuron.h` which depends on `net.h` etc. in infinity. The simple solution as I see it? Move definition of `Layer` from `net.h` to `neuron.h`, and don't include `net.h` inside `neuron.h`.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, what would you recommend as the workaround? I need net.h to get the definition of the layers though. That's where I'm stuck mostly.

Comment: rethink your design (maybe first without looking at the code). Conceptually, does the `neuron` really need to know anything about the `net` ?

Comment: Just the layer definition, however I run into the same issue if I turn it into a class as before. It's almost like I need the definition of what a layer is to be accessible as a sort of "global".

Because a neuron -> layer -> net relationship, however the neuron needs to know the definition of layer to get it's input forward and backwards for propagation.

Comment: Read my comment again please. It tells you what to do.

Comment: thank you. So basic I couldn't even see it.

Comment: Still getting the error though, perhaps this wasn't the problem? Changed with the suggested issue by adding the typedef at the end of the header file for neuron. Issue is still the same cat chasing it's own tail, if I define neuron first, then it doesn't have a reference to layer yet, if I define neuron second then it doesn't contain the required definition of layer...

Well I've certainly messed up this design.

Comment: Did you remove the circular header dependency? It must be removed. "Neutron.h" can not include "net.h"

Comment: Yes. Though it didn't help the issue. It's definitively a situation of back to the drawing board. I need to turn the pass reference and method to take an vector of neurons for the pass down rather then using the layer... which is irritating as that's slow. 

I know what the issue is though however now. Thanks guys you've been super helpful.

Comment: @crashmstr Circular includes are possible in C++, but not in such straightforward manner involving only 2 headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just forward declare Neuron in net.h instead of #include "Neuron.h" as in:

```
#include <vector>
class neuron;
typedef std::vector<neuron> layer;

class net {
    std::vector<layer> layer_;
public:

};

class neuron {
    void feed_forward(layer&);
};
```

But I can't see why the comment by Some Programmer Dude isn't working for you as that should be sufficient.